# Unable to run Optaplanner Web Example

Tags: optaplanner

When I try to Run the optaplanner 6.3.0-SNAPSHOT web example from eclipse (after building with maven and the run on the Server). I am getting the following exception, I tried to deploy the war (downloaded with source code) file directly to tomcat almost similar error shown there as well

```
 java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/optaplanner-webexamples]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/optaplanner-webexamples]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet mapping specifies an unknown servlet name javax.ws.rs.core.Application
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3071)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3050)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureContext(ContextConfig.java:1372)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1176)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5066)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

    Jun 03, 2015 10:58:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
    SEVERE: A child container failed during start
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:439)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:769)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:625)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:925)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

    Jun 03, 2015 10:58:39 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:625)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:769)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:439)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:925)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more

    Jun 03, 2015 10:58:39 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
    INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    Jun 03, 2015 10:58:39 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
    INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
    Jun 03, 2015 10:58:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
    INFO: Stopping service Catalina
    Jun 03, 2015 10:58:39 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
    INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    Jun 03, 2015 10:58:39 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
    SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:303)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:479)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:818)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:532)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:588)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:859)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)

    Jun 03, 2015 10:58:39 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
    INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
    Jun 03, 2015 10:58:39 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
    SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:303)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:479)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:818)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:532)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:588)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:859)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
```

Comment: On WildFly 8.1 it should work. I am not sure it will continue to be able to support tomcat, as we need JAX-RS (but we might build a tomcat distribution war for it too).

Comment: Thanks Geoffrey, I will try it on Wildly as well, Currently i am working some other module and project security related setup, We are planning to use Optaplanner in our project for vehicle routing and i am really excited, Hopefully it will be stable until that time

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet can you provide some instruction of how to run the web example?

Comment: Unzip WildFly 9.x Final, deploy war file, open `localhost:8080/optaplanner-webexamples-6.3.0.Final`

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded in making the 6.3 web example run in tomcat by replacing the following piece of code in your project web.xml file:

```
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

for this servlet configuration code(taken from 6.2 web example):

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>VrpShowScheduleServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.optaplanner.webexamples.vehiclerouting.VrpShowScheduleServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>VrpShowScheduleServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/vehiclerouting/showSchedule.png</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

I run Optaplanner Web Example (version 7.23.0.Final) in this way.

**step0**, Download `optaplanner-distribution-7.23.0.Final.zip` from [OptaPlanner website](https://www.optaplanner.org/) and unzip distribute package, find `optaplanner-webexamples.war`.

**step1**, Write an Dockerfile.

```
FROM jboss/wildfly:14.0.1.Final
MAINTAINER zbr

COPY ./optaplanner-webexamples.war /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/optaplanner-webexample.war

RUN /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/add-user.sh admin admin456 --silent

CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0"]
```

**step3**, Build docker image.

```
docker build -t optaplanner-webexample:latest .
```

**step4**, Run.

```
docker run -ti --rm -p 8080:8080 -p 9990:9990 optaplanner-webexample:latest
```

**step5**, Test.

```
firefox http://localhost:8080/optaplanner-webexample
```

It works.